# w3c validator error: Saw U+0000 in stream

Tags: html, validation, w3c-validation

**HTML5 Validator Error:
Saw U+0000 in stream.**

From what I gather this is a hidden character. I can't seem to find where it's coming from. I've tried copying from textmate to textedit and back to see if it would erase any hidden formatting... no luck! Can't seem to find anything about this anywhere!

Any help would be greatly appreciated, Thanks!

supergiantlabs.com

---

UPDATE:

I just copied the source into a plain html file and all those errors went away. That leads me to believe its in some php file somewhere... somehow. Any ideas on how to track these characters down?

Comment: For what it's worth, I want to add that the w3c-validator isn't anything very important at all. It shows how much your html is compliant to the official standards, but in practice no browser _renders_ it according to those same standards. Most of the time, sites have hundreds of errors and still look good, while if you're restricting yourself to these standards you will be seriously limited in terms of what you can make your site to look like. Besides, you will be wasting your time with trying to figure out errros like these.

Answer (score 0):

For me it looked like it was unnecessary new lines. For example mine said the same error for line 165, line 165 had nothing on it. So i deleted the blank link, re-validated and GREEN. Did you even find out what yours was?

*EDIT Actually after deleting those errors for the past 30 minutes, I'm pretty sure its from copy and pasting from something, mine was powerpoint. But it still doesn't make much sense since we're creating pages in a plain text editor.. but it rare when errors actually make sense.

Comment: Please note that randomly telling about a similar situation isn't a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

First copy your last successful coding from the History and paste again instead of the error coding. And While doing mistake on HTML tags (Myself done as  deleting `</div>` from `<div class=col-md-12></div>`), Then you will get error for HTML. From that just disable the Error Checking and Cont..